# Bounties affecting privileges

Tags: support, bounty

If you offer a bounty and the resulting point drop in reputation would put you below a threshold for a certain privilege, do you lose that privilege or does it just delay acquisition of new privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). It is explained pretty clear in the second bullet point.

> If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any
>   privileges, you will lose access to those privileges.